# generate PDF from link PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf, html-to-pdf

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');


$html.= "Here I shoud have to call a php Generated html file named 'report_pdf.php'";
$mpdf=new mPDF('c', 'A4-L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// $mpdf->SetOrientation('L');

$mpdf->Output();
```

In the Above code in HTML variable I want to call the PHP file which is generating a HTML codes
Note:  Not by using `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `file_get_contents` maybe you can use CURL for this, example:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/report_pdf.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The `$content` variable will have the HTML code in it if the call succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use output buffering [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) / [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).

Replace:

```
$html.= "Here I shoud have to call a php Generated html file named 'report_pdf.php'";
```

With:

```
ob_start();
include('report_pdf.php');
$html .= ob_end_clean();
```

Though it depends on how the `report_pdf.php` file is structured (what it needs or does) and what you mean by *"Generated html file named 'report_pdf.php'"*

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, it work for me.
But i used **TCPDF**

```
$pdf=new mPDF('c', 'A4-L');
$pdf->AddPage();

        // FETCH HTML
        ob_start();
        include_once(CONTENT_PATH."filename.php");
        $rpcontent=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        // FETCH HTML

$htmlcontent = $rpcontent;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();

$pdf->Output($pdf_file, "I"); // I for sending the file inline to the browser
$pdf->Output(REPORT_PATH.test.pdf, "F"); //F for saving output to file
```